# Failed to resolve module specifier 'my-npm-package'

Tags: node.js, npm, import, module, package

I'm testing npm package called "my-npm-package".

**I tried to use the module in another project :**

```
import { route } from "my-npm-package";
console.log(route);
```

**But I got this error :**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "my-npm-package". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

**Here's my package contents :**

```
my-npm-package/
├─ lib/
│  ├─ index.js
├─ package.json
```

**index.js**

```
export const route = () => {
   ...
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-npm-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/my-npm-package.git"
  }
}
```

In addition to this, I tried transpiling and bundling using webpack and babel, but the same error still occurred.

I searched Google for related information and looked through the stack overflow, but I don't know the solution.